# Nuget in Vs2010 throws a 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.' exception when I open my project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

If I open Vs2010 and then open the Package Manager Console host V 2.0 and 2.2 (tried both)

The console starts fine,

If I then open my soloution this error appears in the console

Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

If I open my soloutionfirst, and then open the console I get the same error.

Any time I run a command I get the same error instantly.

If I load a different project, which my current project is a copy of, it loads fine.

Bad soloution Name

SpamisDataMigrationTestingTool

Good soloution Name

SAAS3G

The only obvious difference is the lenght of the soloution name... the bad sln is a copy of the good sln with the names changed, some files deleted and some new unit/integration tests added..

Does anyoe have any idea what might be causing this?
Any help is greatly appreicated.

Comment: Can you try if same happens for a basic plain vanilla project. For example a class library project.

Comment: I've already tried other soloutions, do you mean add a vanilla project to the bad soloution, or try it in a new vanilla siloution with a vanilla project in it (which I expect to work fine since other soloution on my box work fine, just this one causes the issue)

Comment: I tried it with longnamelongnamelongnamelongnamelongnam solution name and it worked fine on VS 2010 and NuGet 2.2  It possible to share the bad solution and I can give it a try?

Comment: All other soloutions worked just the new one was broken, it was a corrputed nuget.config file as in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nuget.Config got altered on copying and renaming the path "JCDCHelper.project" got changed to 
"JcdcHelper.project"... this caused the arithmetic over flow exception

(Nuget.config pointed to a non existant path)